# Function writing "wrong" value to register - PIC18F

Tags: c, embedded, pic, pic18

I've written a function in which you should able to input a number and the function then  calculates the value to write to the register. However it looks like it's writing the "wrong" value to the register. I've used a calculator and wolframalpha to confirm that I'm not screwing up order of operations. The function is listed below:

```
void SetFrequency_Hz(int Freq) {
    PR4 = ((41667000 / (4 * 16 * Freq)) - 1);
}
```

When I try to set the Frequency to 20kHz (20,000Hz), I would need to set the PR4 register to 32. Which in theory if I put in the 20000 calue into the function should be spit out, BUT it's spitting out 179 for some reason. Any guesses why?

MCU: PIC18F67J60
IDE: MP LAB X

Comment: What size is int on a pic18f - how many bits?

Comment: @barny I see what your getting at (PR4 is an 8bit register).I've already tried casting the PR4 and or result as an u8 to no avail. Like so: 

PR4 = (u8) ((41667000 / (4 * 16 * Freq)) - 1);

Comment: It's not the size of the 8-bit register that's important because the expected value of `32` fits. It's the size of C's `int` type. If it is 16 bits the calculation won't work, you need to use a 32-bit type. For example `((41667000UL / (64UL * Freq)) - 1);`

Comment: Huh, I ever knew. Where can I find out more about this?

Comment: Consult the compiler manual. Or try `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(int));` which should give 2, 4, or 8 (bytes).

Comment: No `printf`? Whatever, put it in a `size_t` variable and check it with the debugger. Or on the LCD or however you get output!

Comment: When you fix the arithmetic overflow in the intermediate results you will still end up with 31 not 32. Integer divide truncates toward zero. So the resultant frequency will be 41667000 / ((PR4 + 1) * 64 ) (~20.345Hz when PR4 == 31, ~19.729MHz for 32)

Comment: Avoid 32 bit arithmetic entirely, if possible. 32 bit precision doesn't seem needed here so drop Hz for kHz or MHz.

Comment: @SamW: 1) do yourself a favor: add `#include <stdint.h>` and be explicit about your integer sizes, i.e. use `int32_t` or `int16_t` and make sure you understand the width of the operands, 2) make note of your actual required resolution and dynamic range - if 20000 maps to 32, state which number maps to 30 or 31 and whether you need the resolution at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since in PIC18 a `int` type would be only [16 bits](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/tutorials-code/tutorials-microchip/c18-data-types), the somewhat arcane [implicit conversion rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) in C will cause intermediate results in your expression to be truncated.  I am surprised that your compiler did not issue a warning for the literal 41667000 since that clearly will not fit in a PIC18 `int` type in any case.

The problem can be solved easily by using explicit literal type suffixes to change the overall type of the expression:

```
PR4 = 41667000ul / (64ul * Freq) - 1u ;
```

or if the required frequency resolution is in KHz, you can scale the expression:

```
PR4 = 41667u / (64u * (Freq/1000)) - 1u ;
```

It should be noted however that in both these cases the *real* value of 41667000 / (64 x 20x10<sup>3</sup>)) - 1 is ~31.55 so the value in  PR4 will be 31 not 32, and will result in an *actual* frequency of 20345Hz.

To round to the *nearest* integer value of the *real* expression:

```
PR4 = (41667000ul / (32ul * Freq) - 1u) / 2 ;
```

That will result in PR4=32 and a frequency of 19729Hz.

It may be useful to have the function return the actual achieved frequency:

```
unsigned SetFrequency_Hz( unsigned ideal_freq ) 
{
    PR4 = (41667000ul / (32ul * ideal_freq ) - 1u) / 2u ;

    // Return actual achievable frequency
    return 41667000ul / ((PR4 + 1ul) * 64ul)
}
```